# Can not invoke callback defined in beforeDestory hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to write a simple todoList using vue.js and I want to save those todos into cookies before the vue instance is destroyed. But I find it weird that though I wrote callback in `beforeDestory` hook, the hook is never called.

I checked Vue documents and could not find any hint.

when I tried to 
save those todos into cookies by adding callback to `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload`, it works.

my code is like

```
computed: {
  todos() {
    return this.$store.getters.todos
  },
...
},
beforeDestroy() {
  myStorage.setTodos(this.todos)
}
```

todos is a array defined in store.js, which has been imported in main.js, like

```
import myStorage from '@/utils/storage'
...
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: myStorage.getTodos()
    ...
  },
  getters: {
    todos: state => state.todos
  }
```

and myStorage is defined as:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const todoKey = 'todo'

const setTodos = (todos) => {
  Cookies.set(todoKey, JSON.stringify(todos))
}

const getTodos = () => {
  const todoString = Cookies.get(todoKey)
  let result = []
  if (todoString) {
    const todoParsed = JSON.parse(todoString)
    if (todoParsed instanceof Array) {
      result = todoParsed
    }
  }
  return result
}

export default {
  setTodos: setTodos,
  getTodos: getTodos
}
```

I am using `vue 2.6.10`, and my project is constructed by vue-cli3.
I develop this todolist using Chrome on Window 10.

I expect that after I close the window or after I refresh the window, the todolist can still fetch todo written previously from cookies. But the fact is that the `beforeDestory` hook is never called.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the window, the component's `beforeDestroy()` is not called, because you are not programmatically destroying the component, but ending the entire browser session.

A better solution would simply to call `myStorage.setTodos` whenever the `todos` object in the component is mutated. You can do that by setting up a watcher for the computed property:

```
computed: {
  todos() {
    return this.$store.getters.todos
  },
},
watch: {
    todos() {
        myStorage.setTodos(this.todos)
    }
}
```

Altertively, you let the VueX store handle the storage. It is unclear from your question if you are mutating the `todos` state: if you are mutating it, you can also do `myStorage.setTodos` in the store. The actual component can be dumb in that sense, so that all it needs to do is to update the store.

Comment: Oh, that is helpful, thanks a lot. But what if I just want to save those items once just before I leave the page, or is there any better solution?

Comment: @jimmy You can listen to the `onbeforeunload` event, but that means annoying the user with a dialog/modal before they leave. Constantly saving the todo list whenever it is mutated helps to prevent state loss when, e.g. the user force quits the browser/tab, the computer shuts down unexpectedly, and etc. If you are worried about performance, you can always throttle/debounce the frequency that the cookie is set.

Comment: Aha, it seems I am still not familiar with javasrcipt :p and I still have a long way to go. It it my first time to ask question in stack overflow, I am really thankful for you answer.